# URL Rewriting for virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, virtualhost

I am having a web application hosted in my server with virtual directory. Application throwing errors because of VD as mismatching of path. Due to some application drawback, i am unable to change application path that are hard coded.

I want to know is it possible for me to rewrite URL in order to skip virtual directory from URL? if yes then how to do it?

**EDIT-** Also my application is based on MVC framework.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/~(.+)  http://newserver/~$1  [R,L]

Comment: do YOU WANT TO HIDE THE vd FROM THE URL OR JUST NOT HAVING TO PUT IT?

Comment: Want to hide it. Moreover if we remove it from URL, will it work? M not sure, Can you please provide some more descriptive answer along with some sample code. It will surly helpful for me. Thank you.